# Why isn't the variable in the function passing to the HTML article?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, article

I can get the variable to display in the function as an alert but I can't get the variable to pass to the article.  What am I doing wrong?

I know "a" is holding the correct info because I've displayed it with an alert.

I've tried passing the variable using: placeholderContent.recipientName = a;

I've tried declaring the variable outside and inside the function but that didn't work either.

I've tried making a nested function to pass the variable.

I'm new to javascript and have spent hours researching this and trying different methods and I can't get this to work.  I hope someone can help me!

```js
 function validateForm() {           
                a = document.forms["inviteForm"]["recipientName"].value;
                if (a == "") {
                    alert("Name must be filled out.");
                return false;
                         }
                document.getElementById("recipientName").textContent = a;
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="pageForm">
            <form action="#" Name=inviteForm onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                <label for="recipientName">Recipient name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="recipientName" id="recipientName" placeholder="Enter your Recipient Name" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
        </section>

        <article id="placeholderContent">
            Hello <span id="recipientName"></span>!
        </article>
```

The variable recipientName should be displayed on the page after the user inputs the name in the form and clicks on the submit button.

Comment: ok but I have to submit it on the same page...that's what my homework says to do

Comment: after I click the submit button I still see the input on the form displayed

Comment: Forms are submitted to a server. Are you using one?

Comment: function submitForm(){
            document.getElementById("recipientName").textContent = a;
            }
         window.onload=submitForm();      Now it says "a" is undefined

Comment: I'm not using a server.

Comment: @Dee you can't pass the variable to the next page if you are not using a server. you can only put it in another location in the html with javascript. The only thing wrong with your code is the duplicate id. anyways, if you submit the form you won't see anything happening without a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id is unique and you used `recipientName` both in the `article` and in the `input` field, you can't use it twice in the same page. I changed the id in article and everything is working fine.

```js
 function validateForm() {           
            a = document.forms["inviteForm"]["recipientName"].value;
            if (a == "") {
                alert("Name must be filled out.");
            return false;
                     }
            document.getElementById("recipientName1").textContent = a;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="pageForm">
        <form action="#" Name=inviteForm onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <label for="recipientName">Recipient name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="recipientName" id="recipientName" placeholder="Enter your Recipient Name" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </section>

    <article id="placeholderContent">
        Hello <span id="recipientName1"></span>!
    </article>
```

Comment: You are amazing!  Thank you, thank you, thank you! You have no idea how long I have been working on this and I knew it was going to be a stupid error on my part.

Comment: it was a mistake, I accidentally did that.  Sorry it took so long to correct!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1. Return `false` at the end of `validateForm()` function so that the page doesn't refresh
2. Change the id of the `span` element within which you are trying to display the data. Currently, the id is conflicting with the id of the `input` element.

Here is the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Invite Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>    
    <section id="pageForm">
        <form action="#" Name=inviteForm onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <label for="recipientName">Recipient name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="recipientName" id="recipientName" placeholder="Enter your Recipient Name" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </section>

    <article id="placeholderContent">
        Hello <span id="recipientNameDisplay"></span>!
    </article> 

  <script>
    function validateForm() {           
      a = document.forms["inviteForm"]["recipientName"].value;
      if (a == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out.");
        return false;
      }
      document.getElementById("recipientNameDisplay").textContent = a;
      return false;
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```